# Angular 1 printing data from services callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with printing data from controller at my view. Can someone look and tell me how can I do to print this object at html? I try bind like this: vm.data = data butit's not working.

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('appCtrl', appSettings);


  function appSettings($scope, dataProvider){
    let vm = this;
    vm.name = "Test app";

  //Take data from services / refreshed 1s
  dataProvider.subscribe(function(data){
      console.log(data); // Here is object, but I do not know how to print it at HTML
    });


  }
```

html:

```
<aside>
  {{vm.name}}

<ul data-ng-repeat="n in vm.data">
  <li>{{n.name}}</li>
</ul>


<p>{{vm}}</p>


Data:
{{ data }}


</aside>
```

And services sth like this:

```
function dataProvider(){
return {
   subscribe: subscribe
}

function subscribe(callback){
   do sth and get data to ObjectVar;
   callback(ObjectVar);
}

}
```

'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
            controller : "appCtrl",
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindings: {
              dane: '='
            }
        });
    }]);
```

and now i would like to print this ObjectVar which in controller is data, but I do not know how.

Comment: try like that:  $scope.data and in your html {{data}}

Comment: it is not working, I was trying like this

Comment: there will be a `=` after `dataProvider.subscribe` right?

Comment: no, it's callback which return data

Comment: Try to add more code, it will be useful to understand better your problem.

Comment: can someone help? I do not know how to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

see code snippet might help you

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.service('serviceInvoke', function () {
          return {
            subscribe : subscribe
          };
          function subscribe() {
            return "myname";
          }
         });
      
         myApp.controller('myApp', ['$scope', 'serviceInvoke', function($scope, serviceInvoke){
          
           $scope.data = serviceInvoke.subscribe();
         }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller = "myApp">{{data}}
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have not forgot to add 'controllerAs' property in your route or as an attribute in your template.
If you added that then your code

```
vm.data = data
```

should work fine.

And if not, then you should write this:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('appCtrl', appSettings);

function appSettings($scope, dataProvider){
    let vm = this;
    vm.name = "Test app";

    //Take data from services / refreshed 1s
    dataProvider.subscribe(function(data){
        console.log(data); // Here is object, but I do not know how to print it at HTML
        $scope.data = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
            controller : "appCtrl",
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindings: {
              dane: '='
            }

but, it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

try With this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller= "myApp as vm">{{vm.data}}
  </div> 
</div>
```